# XML Standard for Real Estate property

Tags: xml, properties, standards

Is there a standard XML format for property listings?

I've found a couple:

- reaxml1 reaxml.realestate.com.au/docs/reaxml1-xml-format.html
- RELML www.xml.com/98/08/real/relml-dtd.html

but which is best / most used? Has anyone created xml property listings using these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Australia at least, the "de facto" standard is REAXML. Easily the most used real estate XML specification in that country. In my work I've created both importers and exporters of REAXML data. In South Africa I know of at least one web dev firm that accepts REAXML (for remax.com.au)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that as a correct anser - doesn't seem to be much of a standard out there. REAXML looks good, will try it out.
Out of interest, which web-dev company are you referring to? Would like to chat to them.

Answer (score 3):

The huge one for real estate is called [RETS](http://www.reso.org/specifications/) and is supported by many of the major search portals and MLSes.

There's also a similar standard called MITS for rental properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the defacto standard in Australia in the REAXML feed. When trying to import the data into your application or importing system like WP All import you need to parse the files into a single file for import. This was a huge pain several years ago and I created a simple REAXML parser that could be imported into WordPress. My script works outside of WordPress so you could use it with other applications if needed. Some details are here about the way it works

http://www.realestateconnected.com.au/wordpress-plugin/reaxml-parser-script-for-website-importer-wordpress-joomla-magento-real-estate-xml-feed/